# Variable passed to function isn't set to the value I assigned to it

Tags: c, memory, variable-assignment

In order to return the ith digit from the left of a given number, I created this function:

```
int ith(unsigned long x, int i)
{
    int count=0;
    unsigned long y = x;

    do
    {
        y /= 10;
        count++;
    } while (y > 0);
    if (i > count)
        return -1;
    count -= i;
    while (count > 0)
    {
        x /= 10;
        count--;
    }
    return x % 10;

}
```

However, when the input for the function is 2,2. It took alot of time for the function to finnish;
so i looked up into the debugger, and noticed that `count==54353453`  and `count` never recieve the `0` i assigned him.

**EDIT**
Here's the rest of my code, as some suggested may be the source of this error.

```
int main()
{
    int x, i,result;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a number and the digit you want to retrieve.\nEnter a negative number to exit\n");
        scanf("%ul %d", &x, &i);
        if (x<0)
        {
            printf("Operation Aborted.. Exiting....\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            result = ith(x, i);
            if (result == -1)
            {
                printf("Error: There are no such amount of digits to retrieve from that location\n");
                continue;
            }
            printf("The %dth digit of the number %ul is %d\n", i, x, result);
        }

    } while (x >= 0);
}
```

Comment: Can´t reproduce http://ideone.com/9Qqyzp Probably there is a UB problem somewhere else in your code.

Comment: `x` is not correctly typed: `int` / `unsigned long` / `long`

Comment: `%ul` is wrong in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
scanf("%ul %d", &x, &i);
```

uses the wrong specifier for scanning in `x`.

As `x` is defined `int`, it has to be

```
scanf("%d %d", &x, &i);
```

or you define `x` as `unsigned long` then it has to be

```
scanf("%lu %d", &x, &i);
```

---

The same kind of issue is here:

```
printf("The %dth digit of the number %ul is %d\n", i, x, result);
```

Comment: note that, looking at the prototype of `ith`, it's probably the other way around: `x` has the wrong type (should be `unsigned long`)

Comment: thanks. My problem was:
A. i didn't declared X as nessecery.
B. I wrote %ul instead of %lu in the scanf function

Comment: @basddsasda: The compiler should have warned you about the latter case.